# values of all rows is getting changed when I am trying to change the value of just first row of a matrix in python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, matrix, list-manipulation

```
  cost = [[-1]*2]*2
  matrix = [[2,3],[4,5]]
  for i in range(2):
      for j in range(2):
           if i == 0:
               cost[i][j] = matrix[i][j]        
  print(cost)
```

I am expecting output  **[[2,3],[-1, -1]]**, but the actual output is **[[2, 3],[2,3]]**. I am not understanding that why are second-row elements are getting changed along with the first row?

Comment: Because when you do `cost[i][j] = matrix[i][j]` and then change cost it will qutomatically change matrix, it is the wrong way to have different output. Its better to print 2 different variables without any assignment operator (=)

Comment: `cost = [[ -1 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(2)]` might help as it creates different inside lists and not adds the same listreference multiple times - yours adds the same reference multiple times and all references point to the same internal data. changing data is reflected over all references

Comment: Thanks @PatrickArtner. It is giving the expected output after changing the code.